# Remove dash from string but not from middle when its surrounded by (a-z)

Tags: java, regex, string

I read similar questions but those are not answer exactly to my question.

i want to remove any dash from my string but not that dash in middle of string that surrounded by (a-z) or (A-Z) like my example test case.

i already use this regex code but it clean all dash:

```
string.replaceAll("\\-", "");
```

---

### Test Case

- --good
- -good
- **g-ood***
- g--ood
- good-
- good--

---

### Result

- good
- good
- **g-ood***
- good
- good
- good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex to do that is the right thing to do. However, your regex is capturing **every** hyphens. What you need is to check for letter before and after.

```
((?<!\w)-|-(?!\w))
```

This regex will look for hyphens that have nothing before **OR** hypen that has nothing behind and replace them.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Using this regex, you can replace those occurrence by nothing, like you did before.

```
string.replaceAll("((?<!\\w)-|-(?!\\w))", "");
```

[here is a regex101 for you to test more cases](https://regex101.com/r/8Z1ibx/1)